# Grouping Components in Eagle

Tags: eaglecad

I'm wondering how I can these empty rectangles on eagle and label them, so I can reference the blocks my circuit has. For example:

[image]

When I open the example file, right click on the rectangle and select "properties", I see that it's type is "Wire", and that it is on layer "94: Symbols". However, when I manually try to draw with wires, the wires are green and there is no way I can select which layer they are on.

How do I make the blocks such as in the schematic above?

EDIT: The "blocks" I'm describing are those that are letting me know which part of the circuit is "Power from ATX PS" and which part it "Power from Screw Terminals & Vreg".

I'm having trouble making the simple rectangle that delimits these two blocks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use a particular software package.

Comment: I would think that, given there is an eagle tag, it would be ok to ask eagle questions. Also, I don't see why other people who use eagle would not benefit from it. I think also that  the fraction of those that use eagle is greater than the fraction of people that would understand some of the very specific questions that I've seen here. Should I delete this and explain why I heavily disagree with that rule on the metaexchange?

Comment: @DaveTweed  I don't think this is off-topic.  This is about a specialized EDA software package.  The question may or may not be clear, perhaps.  But not off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select the "wire" tool, and then draw a wire on the schematic, it does indeed come out as green because its on the Nets layer (layer 91).

However, if you go to the toolbar at the top and change the layer to "94 Symbols" *before* drawing the wire, it will draw a red line and not an electrical connection.

[image: How to select symbols layer]